# C : #define usage

Tags: c

The output of the following script is 20. But can anyone please elaborate why it is so, and not 110

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
#define MAXLEN MAX+1

int main()
{
  printf("%d", MAXLEN * 10);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Operator precedence: `10 + 1 * 10` is 20, not 110. But this is over-asked so much that I feel physical pain when I see yet another instance of this question.

Comment: #define is just a replacement. #define is not a function. #define MAXLEN (MAX+1) will produce 110.

Comment: People should really read that C tutorial **carefully.** I mean, reading, understanding, memorizing, you know.

Comment: have a look on your programme by using `cc -E filename.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `MAX` is 10, `MAXLEN` is 10+1, and you print 10+1*10 which is 20.

Macro expansion substitutes the strings verbatim and that's why you must use parenthesis when defining them. For example:

```
#define MAXLEN (MAX+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider what this expands to

```
MAXLEN * 10 == MAX+1 * 10
```

which, when you consider operator precedence gives

```
MAX + (1 * 10) == 10 + (1 * 10)
               == 10 + 10
               == 20
```

You probably wanted

```
#define MAXLEN (MAX+1)
```

instead.

Comment: @simonrc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096361/c-define-usage#comment26489693_18096361

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree that this question shouldn't have answers since it's duplicated, but his answer is good and explains it well. This is helpful for the OP.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Sorry, but this question should not be answered. It should be marked as a duplicate. Anything else (including "helpful" answers) only encourage lazinesss.

Comment: Downvote should be done if its a wrong answer.. But the answer is perfectly right!!

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy The **attitude** behind the answer is what's wrong.

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy Completely agree with H2CO3 on this.  Answering dups, even if those are complete and well-explained ones, is **bad**.

Answer (score 2):

```
MAXLEN * 10 => MAX + 1 * 10 => 10 + (1 * 10) => 20
```